# C++ Parse different JSONs into one struct or class

Tags: c++, json, algorithm, oop, data-structures

I get different JSONs from API in my C++ project.
My goal is to parse different JSONs into one struct or class in my back-end code.

For example I have

> {
>       "access_token": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
>       "expires_in": 3600,
>       "scope": "token", }

and

> {
>       "name": "example",
>       "updatedAt": {
>                       "date": "2015-01-30 14:03:28",
>                       "timezone_type": 3,
>                       "timezone": "Europe/Stockholm"
>                   }, }

Now I have two structs for above JSONs but I want to use one struct or class for all JSONs.

Which algorithm is more suitable for this case

Thanks in advance

Comment: These are very different, so I would keep them separate. The only common structure could be a [`union`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union) of `struct`s.

Comment: To  be clear. The question is not about parsing the JSON, but about refactoring the representation of the parsed data in your code? Further, you are already able to store your data, as it is predictable enough that you can write specific structs for the representation (and having done so)? And now you are asking about a generic struct that is able to represent whatever imaginable JSON?

Comment: Yes moooeeeep! I can parse json data in my code, but I would like to have one struct or class instead of two or three. I want to a generic struct or class and an algorithm for parsing all JSON data into one struct or class.

Comment: What you want is quite awful. You have two different structs with totally different meaning. What you can do is have a class with an enum as first member indicating what it is, followed by a pointer to one struct which can be NULL, followed by a pointer to the second struct which can also be NULL.

Comment: You are right but I believe there is a solution

Comment: Then you can either reimplement or use an existing parser library. It's not trivial to create this flexible key/value storages that are also infinitely nestable in C++ (and usually not desirable either). You better keep it simple. Maybe polymorphism would be an option to make them _appear_ as structs of the same type at some point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "built in" class for JSON format in native C++.
more than that , JSON are serialized JavaScript objects that can dynamically change in terms of inner member or functions , types and just about everything. 
this is NOT natively achievable in "regular" C++ were everything has to be set in compile time.
Most of the JSON parsers for C++ uses some combination of std::map with some "JSONValue" Objects which holds a stub for everything JSON can hold (int , float , string, boolean , another JSONValue etc.)

I think you should use one of these parsers instead of trying to figure out JSON parsing your own . I personally use JSONCPP if my program do not use Unicode and SimleJSON if it does .

Comment: I know that. I asked this question to know the suitable algorithm!